# how to receive mail commandline?

Tags: email, command-line, gmail-imap

Can anybody suggest me a way to receive mail from commandline and save it to a file. i have tried some tool but those were of no use. i tried getmail and popclient. but every time i get an error. may be my syntax is wrong.
in getmail i tried this command

```
getmail -u myemail@gmail.com -pw password -s imap.gmail.com -port 110
```

and got error of winsock.dll
i have also tried it with port 993 and in this case it gave error of possible time out
and in popclient i also used this type of settings in config.xml but i got the same error of server not responding.can anybody figure out what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The port number is wrong for gmail, and you need to use the POP access feature of gmail and the POP email server to connect to (`not via imap`).

Gmail uses a secure port and also SSL security.  Enable the `POP retrieval/access` in Gmail configuration and read the `Gmail help` on how to access via POP (for any client) - it will list the `port number` and `server name` and `security encryption`.